# RandomNumberGenerator GetInt32 not defined

Tags: c#, random

I have to change the random number generation in multiple places in the sourcecode I am working on, to use the RandomNumberGenerator class instead of the Random class for security reasons.

After looking at the [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-5.0) I figured I have to use the Create() method to make an instance of RandomNumberGenerator. Everything is fine, I could use the GetBytes() function without a problem, but I can't seem to be able use the GetInt32() which is used for generating ints. I've first tried calling it from the instance, then I saw in the documentation that it is a static function, so i've tried calling it like so `RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(256)` but it doesn't contain a definition, the only methods that intellisense suggests me are Create, Equals and ReferenceEquals and I am quite confused as to why?

I have the namespace System.Security.Cryptography included.

I've tried googling around to see implementations, or if someone else had the same question but I couldn't find anything relatable.

EDIT: We are using .net framework 4.8 so I've been looking at the wrong documentation and [this should be the correct one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=netframework-4.8). This one doesn't contain a definition for GetInt32 or anything like that so now I am not sure what should I use to generate random integers safely.

Comment: In the "applies to" you can see the specified method is not available on .NET Framework or .NET Core versions prior to 3.0, so my guess would be you're using one of those.

Comment: ^^ in other words: Please add the framework and version you are on, so we can make suggestions.

Comment: Yep, I've just noticed. We are using .NET framework 4.8 so this is the documentation I should have read

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=netframework-4.8

It seems like this doesn't have a GetInt32 method or anything like that, so I am not sure what should I use to generate random ints

Comment: You can use `GetBytes` to get 4 bytes and convert the result, much as [the implementation on Core does](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/RandomNumberGenerator.cs#L105) (the method that fills a `Span` is not available but the idea is the same).

Comment: If you are stuck to the version (which I guess you are), I'd have a look into how GetInt32 is implemented and just "be inspired" by that ...

Comment: The link that @JeroenMostert posted is now dead. However, I've found the code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/RandomNumberGenerator.cs#L140).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that you are working on a version of the .NET Framework that doesn't support the `RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32()` static method, an easy way to get an integer would be to get some random bytes and use `BitConverter` to convert that to an integer:

```
byte[] rngBytes = new byte[4];

// This could be replaced by your instance of RandomNumberGenerator
RandomNumberGenerator.Create().GetBytes(rngBytes);

// Convert the bytes into an integer
int myInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(rngBytes);
```

Note: You should be aware that the given integer `myInt` could be negative given that this will simply convert the bytes into the equivalent integer value.  You could simply drop the leading bit before converting or just do `myInt = 0 - myInt;` to get a positive.

Comment: This is very helpful, and seems like a simple solution, though I am not sure how could I implement it so the range can be precisely defined? It would be necesarry.

Comment: @66Gramms Have a look into the link Jeroen gave in his comment. Range is taken care of there. Of course you will need to tweak the original implementation a little.

Comment: @66Gramms What range do you need?  There's a simple way to limit the numbers to a range but there's likely to be a modulo bias depending upon how it's done.

Comment: I think I will go with the core implementation that Jeroen linked, thank you for all the help

Comment: @Martin to avoid issues with negatives one can change from ToInt32() to ToUInt32()